# Getting Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, xelement

```
private static void InsertClinicalItemMaster(XElement elecim)
    {
        //Insert To DataBase Logic
        try
        {
            String strStatus = "";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=sa;Password=saadmin");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Insert_ClinicalItemMaster", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@xmlData", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = Convert.ToString(elecim);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@retValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strStatus;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

When the "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();" executes then I am getting above "OutOfMemoryException" . I assume that the problem with Converting XElement to String.

Comment: What is the size of data which should be returned by that SPROC?

Comment: Around 2 lakhs records ( of Sql Data Table consists 25 columns)

Answer (score 1):

You try to fetch too big chunk of data to handle in one string (which is an anti-pattern in itself).

Please consider using a more semantically correct alternative - creating a class with [Enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and fetching data record-by-record. Or - better - just use a standard solution (LINQ-to-SQL/Entity Framework). This will allow you to not waste memory on string parsing and get the actual objects (which occupy much less memory)

Using a stored procedure to pack 200 000 (or any number of) objects into a string to parse it in an application... Well... Just never do that again :)

Comment: What is the best way to insert lots Xml data to sql server ? Can u help in this ?

Comment: @Kittu: Best way in my opinion is parse XML locally, not on the server and insert items using LINQ-to-SQL or plain SQL. XML reading for very large files can be streamed (example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387013.aspx)